# Serving nodejs static files in the same domain as my wordpress WEB-SERVER NGINX

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, nginx

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
servername www.domain.com.br;
return 301 http://www.domain.com.br$requesturi;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
location / {
#try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;}
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
expires max;
log_not_found off;
}
location /sistema/ { //RUNNING NODEJS RIGHT HERE
proxy_read_timeout 600;
client_max_body_size       500M;
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_set_header Host      $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

}
}
```

I would like to serve my static files or my uploaded files from my NODEJS System through

www.mydomain.com.br/sistema/uploads/path/tofile

www.mydomain.com.br/sistema/views/path/to/views

I am using express.static(__dirname + '/public'); as static folder;

Is there a possibility? I have been trying to set my server blocks, but I get 404 nginx using those url's above.

Thank you,

Enrico Alvarenga

Comment: Can you post the 404 error from the NGINX access log?

Comment: yes, I can  [19/Jan/2017:16:32:33 +0000] "GET /sistema/uploads/LF/Executivo-II/111/zip/Turma-111_contas-jpa.zip HTTP/1.1" 404 105 "-" "

Comment: [19/Jan/2017:16:32:40 +0000] "GET /sistema/public/uploads/LF/Executivo-II/111/galeria/Turma-111_me.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 152

Comment: You're passing the full URL to node, perhaps it can't understand the /sistema/ part? How do you typically access those assets?  Are there any errors in the node.js log?

Comment: What I wanna do is serve all kind of static files inside /public.  However, there are a couple of files the client uploads, it goes to /public/uploads/LF/dynamic/dynamic/zip/zipfile.zip, can u get it? So, I suppose it should be at /sistema/uploads... right? There are no nodejs error logs.

Comment: My question is: what should I do to serve those files through Nginx?

Comment: Easiest way is the have NGINX serve it directly: `location /sistema { alias /public;}`